# Javascript not able to console log or continue

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder why the second console log does not show up in the Browser:

```
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
        if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "_escaped_fragment_") {
            var escapedFragment = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
            console.log('Fragment: ' + escapedFragment);
            var myNode = document.getElementById("rootPanel");
            myNode.innerHTML = '';
            console.log('rootPanel cleared');
            window.history.pushState("_escaped_fragment_", "", "?f=" + escapedFragment);
        }
    }
```

When the first one shows up.

Comment: the div with id = 'rootPanel' is there in the HTML

Comment: Do you have some markup you can post?  Or setup a JsFiddle/Codepen?

Comment: sounds work fine see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97m1t0sg/) , could you post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, seems to work fine.

```js
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
  if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "_escaped_fragment_") {
    var escapedFragment = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
    console.log('Fragment: ' + escapedFragment);
    var myNode = document.getElementById("rootPanel");
    myNode.innerHTML = '';
    console.log('rootPanel cleared');
    window.history.pushState("_escaped_fragment_", "", "?f=" + escapedFragment);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta property="_escaped_fragment_">foo</meta>
<div id="rootPanel">bar</div>
```